# I encountered an error while executing "sudo apt upgrade" on the Ubuntu command line

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, dpkg

Recently, when I was performing system updates on Ubuntu, I found that the terminal always reported errors, but it did not affect the normal installation of other software. However, I still want to figure out what is going on? I am in this post[text](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/ +Source/Linux restricted modules/+bug/2046345) found a similar issue but did not propose a solution
**Complete error message:**

```
有 3 个软件包没有被完全安装或卸载。
解压缩后会消耗 0 B 的额外空间。
您希望继续执行吗？ [Y/n] 
正在设置 linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1+5) ...
linux-image-nvidia-6.5.0-14-generic: constructing .ko files
make: arch/x86/Makefile.postlink: 没有那个文件或目录
make: *** 没有规则可制作目标“arch/x86/Makefile.postlink”。 停止。
make: arch/x86/Makefile.postlink: 没有那个文件或目录
make: *** 没有规则可制作目标“arch/x86/Makefile.postlink”。 停止。
make: arch/x86/Makefile.postlink: 没有那个文件或目录
make: *** 没有规则可制作目标“arch/x86/Makefile.postlink”。 停止。
make: arch/x86/Makefile.postlink: 没有那个文件或目录
make: *** 没有规则可制作目标“arch/x86/Makefile.postlink”。 停止。
make: arch/x86/Makefile.postlink: 没有那个文件或目录
make: *** 没有规则可制作目标“arch/x86/Makefile.postlink”。 停止。
nvidia-drm.ko: 成功
nvidia-modeset.ko: 成功
nvidia-peermem.ko: 成功
nvidia-uvm.ko: 成功
nvidia.ko: 失败
sha256sum: 警告：1 个校验和不匹配
dpkg: 处理软件包 linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.5.0-14-generic (--configure)时出错：
 已安装 linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.5.0-14-generic 软件包 post-installation 脚本 
子进程返回错误状态 1
dpkg: 依赖关系问题使得 linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic-hwe-22.04 的配置工作不能
继续：
 linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic-hwe-22.04 依赖于 linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.5.
0-14-generic (= 6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1+5)；然而：
  软件包 linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.5.0-14-generic 尚未配置。

dpkg: 处理软件包 linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic-hwe-22.04 (--configure)时出错
：
 依赖关系问题 - 仍未被配置
dpkg: 依赖关系问题使得 nvidia-driver-525 的配置工作不能继续：
 nvidia-driver-525 依赖于 nvidia-dkms-525 (<= 525.147.05-1)；然而：
  未安装软件包 nvidia-dkms-525。
  软件包 linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic-hwe-22.04 提供了 nvidia-dkms-525，但它
尚未被配置。
 nvidia-driver-525 依赖于 nvidia-dkms-525 (>= 525.147.05)；然而：
  未安装软件包 nvidia-dkms-525。
  软件包 linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic-hwe-22.04 提供了 nvidia-dkms-525，但它
尚未被配置。

dpkg: 处理�因为错误消息指示这是由于上一个问题导致的错误，没有写入 apport 报告。

因为错误消息指示这是由于上一个问题导致的错误，没有写入 apport 报告。
                                                                    �件包 nvidia
-driver-525 (--configure)时出错：
 依赖关系问题 - 仍未被配置
在处理时有错误发生：
 linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.5.0-14-generic
 linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic-hwe-22.04
 nvidia-driver-525
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The version I am using:
ubuntu 22.04
kernal 6.5.0.14
nvidia-driver 525..147.05

I tried to replace the driver version of 535, but still reported the same error.

dpkg -l | grep nvidia:
[image: dpkg -l | grep nvidia]
[image: dpkg -l | grep nvidia]

dkms status:
[image: dkms status]

grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*:
[image]

lsb_release -a:
[image]

**After upgrading the system version to 23.10, this issue has been temporarily resolved**

Comment: Can you please add `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` and `dkms status` through [edit] to your question?

Comment: Had similar issue and solved it with this [guide](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1).
I ran into this situation, when the partition holding the update information ran out of space and the database got corrupted.

Comment: Hello, I have added it as requested. Please take a look @nobody

Comment: Ähm I see a mix from 22.04 and 23.04 packages. `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and `lsb_release -a` please.

Comment: Hello, I have added it, but the issue did not recur after the system was upgraded to 23.10